# Using Multiple XML Layouts for One Activity

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the line with the 2 **, can someone explain to me why this is happening? I've also tried using a `switch/case` statement with no luck.

```
String test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    **if(test.equals("One")) {**
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
    } else if(test.equals("Two")){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: it because your test is null

Comment: Thank you @PhanVănLinh .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is null and the NullPointerException is raised.

You should initialize that variable.

Moreover, it would be better when you need to check some String with a constant to put the constant variable to `this` object, for example change this:

```
if(test.equals("One"))
```

To this:

```
if("One".equals(test))
```

In this way you are safe even if test will be null.

Comment: Dude, perfect answer with the example. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `NPE` because your `String test` is never initialized, so it's actually `null`.

On the line with the ** you're trying to invoke a method on a `null` reference.

```
if(test.equals("One")) { // Will generate NPE
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
} else if(test.equals("Two")){ // Will generate NPE
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

You have to initialize the variable. And as a good practice you can always check for `null`, like:

```
if (test != null) {
    // do something.
}
```

And like it was said on other answers, you can compare the literals like:

```
"one".equals(test);
```

A suggestion would be not to use "magic numbers" and "magic strings". Declare those literals on your class, like:

```
private static final String STR_ONE = "One";
private static final String STR_TWO = "Two";
```

Then, on your `if/else` do the comparison like this:

```
if (STR_ONE.equals(test)) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
} else if (STR_TWO.equals(test)) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);  
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}
```

More info on `NullPointerException` [here on the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) and on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` variable is `null`. To avoid `null` checks on `String` it is always a good idea to have equals method called on constant value

```
if("One".equals(test)) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
} else if("Two".equals(test)){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```